# String or binary data would be truncated error when inserting into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an insert statement returning the error

> 'String or binary data would be truncated.'

, now i know this would normally be to the fields in the table not being wide enough, however the `SELECT` returns 0 results. How can i get a truncation error when inserting nothing?

Comment: Please share your code in your post.

Comment: You can get this when the optimizer decides to evaluate the conversion before it evaluates the conditions of the `WHERE`. In T-SQL any expression must always be valid regardless of any conditions that you think might limit the circumstances under which it is evaluated, because the optimizer is free to ignore those conditions. You can add an explicit `LEFT` or `CONVERT`, and check for overlong values explicitly with a query first if you need to signal an error for them.

Comment: Do not overlook faulty code in a trigger.